# Two methods to prove the sequence is monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence say,

$ a_n = k^n$

or

$a_{n+1} = (2+a_n)^{1/2}$

Should I use M.I. to prove it or can I just do '$a_{n+1} - a_n$' ?

Comment: Is it if it is a recurrence relation, we use MI.

Comment: If it is a sequence doesn't recurse, we can just subtract one by another?